# Difference between "will be doing" and "will do"

Tags: progressive-aspect, future-constructions

I've just learned the grammar of "will be doing" and I was trying to make sentences with that. But I got confused with the difference between "will do" and "will be doing" in these sentences. Can we use both?

> If his temper tantrum continues, **he'll be lashing out** at anyone at the party tomorrow.

> If his temper tantrum continues, **he'll lash out** at anyone at the party tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the phrases "*will be doing*" or "*will do*" are present in your examples.

However, it might help to know that all three of the following sentences are grammatically correct. Additionally, all three sentences have the same meaning.

> - "If his temper tantrum continues, ***he will be lashing*** out at anyone at the party tomorrow."
> - "If his temper tantrum continues, ***he will*** lash out at anyone at the party tomorrow."
> - If his temper tantrum continues, ***he'll lash out*** at anyone at the party tomorrow.

I will note that all of those sentences are depressing. I do not always know what a person will do the next day. Also, people tend to be more respectful, and show courtesy, to other guests at parties, even when they are feeling angry.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But are you saying that these words are not meaningful together? When I was writing it, I was thinking about a little child who is in his temper tantrum and if it continues, he will act angry to other people.

Comment: This is question is answered at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/546439/how-can-i-understand-the-sentence-1b/546441#546441